# Error in named.conf

Tags: linux, configuration, dns, bind

I am getting the following error:

```
Starting named:
Error in named configuration:
zone blk1999.lab/IN: loaded serial 2001062501
zone localhost.localdomain/IN: loading from master file named.localhost failed: file not found
zone localhost.localdomain/IN: not loaded due to errors.
_default/localhost.localdomain/IN: file not found
zone localhost/IN: loading from master file named.localhost failed: file not found
zone localhost/IN: not loaded due to errors.
_default/localhost/IN: file not found
zone 1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa/IN: loading from master file named.loopback failed: file not found
zone 1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa/IN: not loaded due to errors.
_default/1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa/IN: file not found
zone 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loading from master file named.loopback failed: file not found
zone 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa/IN: not loaded due to errors.
_default/1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa/IN: file not found
zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: loading from master file named.empty failed: file not found
zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: not loaded due to errors.
_default/0.in-addr.arpa/IN: file not found
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Every line ending in "file not found" is due to exactly that - a missing file.

Your "blk19999.lab" zone seems to be loading fine, but all the other zone files either need to be created & populated, or commented out /removed.